# Apply I18 to Ruby on Rails Completed Site.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, i18n-gem

I am new to **Internationalization(I18)**. I want to apply I18 to my Ruby on Rails site but the problem is site is already complete and I don't want to go to each HTML page change the code. I want my site in English, French, and Spanish language.

Please show me the way and I appreciate any example or tutorial for I18.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the development team on your inherited site had future-I18n on their mind when they made the site (e.g. strings are not hardcoded but reference values found in **config/locales/en.yml** using the `I18n.translate` method), then you will have no choice but  to go in and change every file that uses strings you want to translate.

I'm sure you've already found the following references, but just in case, you should probably start with these:

- [Rails I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)
- [Rails I18n Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n)
- [Rails I18n backends Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends)
- Other Rails I18n questions on StackOverflow

As @Dougui pointed out, you probably have a fair amount of work ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but I think there is no way to do this. It's just a very long work... Good luck!